# Depending on the screen size want to replace the image

Tags: jquery

I'm actually trying load image based on its screen size. Code seems to be right but for some reason its not displaying the image. Path is right..Any insight??
Here is my [Page](http://move.clanteam.com/testing.html) and my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/r7nP8/2/)

Comment: why did this question get downvoted so much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following line:

```
$("#wide").attr("src","http://imgur.com/TPwe7");
```

That's putting a `src` attribute on the `div`. You want to put it on the `img` (and use a real image URL):

```
$("img", detector).attr("src","http://i.imgur.com/sW6hi.png");
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

> $("#wide").attr("src","http://imgur.com/TPwe7");

With

> $("#wide").find('img').attr("src","http://imgur.com/TPwe7");